# How to get rid of zero standard error values, missing t-values and p-values

Tags: standard-error, sas, tobit-regression

I was running a couple of Tobit regressions on SAS. Surprisingly, I found that estimates from one model show 0 standard errors, missing (.) t-values and p-values. Why did this happen? What does this scenario imply? If this is not normal, how can I get rid of it?

Please allow me to share the output.

And much thanks for your guidance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typically happens when your [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) is nearly [singular](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70899/what-correlation-makes-a-matrix-singular-and-what-are-implications-of-singularit).  The following SAS article describes your exact situation I believe.

http://support.sas.com/kb/31/714.html

Try re-scaling the variables that have zero standard errors as this is most likely the cause of the problem you are experiencing. I'm guessing that these variables are measured on a scale that is significantly larger/smaller than your other variables, which is leading to the invertibility problems with the Hessian matrix.

You're likely to resolve this problem by standardizing the predictors before running `proc qlim.`  See `proc standard` for this.  Verify that  you have correctly specified your model and didn't accidentally include some variables twice.  It seems this has lead to some other problems noted [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181515/what-does-hessian-is-singular-mean-in-sas-proc-nlin) (the answer there by @placidia is a good one and may help you resolve your issue with `proc qlim`).

If that does't work, try reading through [this article](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/help.pdf) and try some of the suggestions there.

Comment: Previously I have noticed that when SAS encounters such problems, it gives warnings in the log. However, while running this model I have not seen any warnings. About standardizing, the problems are that the first 4 variables are dummies, and sine and cosine variables are actually sine and cosine values. Anyways, do you think the other parameters estimates would still be reliable?